# How can i convert this string type variable in array type?

Tags: php, arrays

how can i convert this string in array passing it through a variable?

```
'NumDoc'=> ['417', '145'], 'dateDoc'=> ['2022-08-12', '2022-08-13'], 'ValueDoc'=> ['100.00', '150.00']
```

When i try this it works fine:

```
array('NumDoc'=> ['417', '145'], 'dateDoc'=> ['2022-08-12', '2022-08-13'], 'ValueDoc'=> ['100.00', '150.00'])
```

But i'm  needing to pass it through a variable as below and it's not working:

```
$string ="'NumDoc'=> ['417', '145'], 'dateDoc'=> ['2022-08-12', '2022-08-13'], 'ValueDoc'=> ['100.00', '150.00']";

array($string);
```

Comment: This is an often asked question. There is no good solution for this, you'd need to implement a fully fledged language parser for that, except if you really can narrow down how that string might look like. Typically you should ask yourself another question is such a situation: how come you have such a string? Could it be you could change that obviously strange situation? So that you do not actually have to solve that problem?

Comment: Is this the only format of your expected input or should this work for anything that can go in an array? It shouldn't be too much to parse the input if it's always at this format (in fact you already have an answer that does this) but anything more is going to be akin to implementing (or using) an `eval` like function with all the security implications that has

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "'NumDoc'=> ['417', '145'], 'dateDoc'=> ['2022-08-12', '2022-08-13'], 'ValueDoc'=> ['100.00', '150.00']";

function convertToArray(string $string): array
{
  $parts = explode('],', $string);

  foreach($parts as $part) {
    $key = trim(str_replace('\'', '', substr($part, 0, strpos($part, '=>'))));
    $value = trim(substr($part, strpos($part, '=> [') + strlen('=> [')));
  
    $new[str_replace('\'', '', $key)] = explode(',', str_replace(['\'', ' ', ']'], '', $value));
  }

  return $new ?? [];
}

var_dump(convertToArray($string));
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  'NumDoc' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '417' (length=3)
      1 => string '145' (length=3)
  'dateDoc' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2022-08-12' (length=10)
      1 => string '2022-08-13' (length=10)
  'ValueDoc' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '100.00' (length=6)
      1 => string '150.00' (length=6)
```

A more elegent approach...

```
function convertToArray(string $string): array
{
  $parts = explode(':', str_replace(['\'', '[', ']', ' '], '', str_replace('],', ':', $string)));

  $result = [];
  array_walk($parts, function ($key) use (&$result) {
    $index = substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '=>'));
    $value = str_replace($index.'=>', '', explode(',', $key));

    $result[$index] = $value;
  });

  return $result;
}
```